# [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed error

Tags: php, implode

Can someone please tell me why this code is not working. I browsed through previous answers and the replies were because the array is not set but here it is set?

```
    $cars = array('Volvo','BMW','Toyota');
    foreach($cars as $val) {
      if( ! empty( $$val )) {
              $felter[] = $val;
              $values[] = $$val;
        }
    }

    $feltstr = implode(',' , $felter);
    $valuestr = "'" . implode("', '", $values) . "'";


$sql= "INSERT INTO my-cars (id, $feltstr) VALUES ('', $valuestr)";
echo $sql;
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be

```
 if( ! empty( $$val )) {
```

this

```
 if( ! empty( $val )) {
```

And inside your foreach change this

```
$values[] = $$val;
```

to this

```
$values[] = $val;
```